# Computation of minimal axis-aligned bounding box of an arc segment.

Tags: geometry, math-software

I'm trying to compute the minimal bounding box of an arc segment so when it's time to render it, I only have to examine pixel coordinates within a minimal rectangular region.  The code below covers the case when $0 \leq \theta_0 \lt \pi/2$.  Was wondering if there is some sort of rotational symmetry so that I don't need 4x the amount of code statements that the box() function already is (1 for each quadrant where $\theta_0$ could be.  The prog language is D.

```
struct Arc {
protected:
Vec2 c;
float r0, r1;
float t0, t1;

invariant() {
    assert(r0 < r1 && t0 < t1);
}

public:
this(in Vec2 center, float radius0, float radius1,
     float theta0, float theta1) 
{
    c = center;
    r0 = radius0;
    r1 = radius1;
    t0 = theta0;
    t1 = theta1;
}

@property Box2 box() {
    double minX, minY, maxX, maxY;

    if (theta0 >= 0) {
        if (theta0 < PI/2) {
            if (theta1 < 2*PI - theta0)
                maxX = r1 * cos(theta0);
            else
                maxX = r1 * cos(theta1);

            if (theta1 <= PI/2) {
                maxY = r1 * sin(theta1);
                minY = r0 * sin(theta0);
                minX = r0 * cos(theta1);
            }
            else {
                maxY = r1;
                if (theta1 <= PI) {
                    if (theta1 - PI/2 > PI/2 - theta0)
                        minY = r0 * sin(PI - theta1);
                    else
                        minY = r0 * sin(theta0);
                    minX = r1 * cos(PI - theta1);
                }
                else {
                    minX = -r1;
                    if (theta1 <= 3*PI/4) 
                        minY = r1 * sin(theta1);
                    else    // 2PI >= theta1 > 3*PI/4 
                        minY = -r1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

My guess is is that you compute which quadrant $\theta_0$ is in, then rotate the whole thing into quadrant 1 which I already have code for (rotate by either $\pi/2, \pi,$ or $3\pi/2$), compute the bounding box in that quadrant, then rotate the bounding box by the same angle, negated.  Would this work?  I think I will need to open up Geogebra and draw some test images to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm only rotating by multiples of $90$ degrees, this should work.  In other words, the quadrant 1-computed bounding box, rotated back $k\cdot 90$ degrees, is still axis-aligned, and obviously still minimal.  And every $\theta_0$ can be brought into quadrant 1 by a multiple-of-$90$-degrees rotation.

```
module bud.arc;

import bud.seeds;
import bud.leaves;

class Arc : Leaf {
protected:
Vec2 c;
float r0, r1;
float t0, t1;

invariant() {
    assert(r0 < r1 && t0 < t1 && 0 <= t0 && t0 <= 2*PI && 0 <= t1 && t1 <= 2*PI);
}

public:
// theta0, theta1 must be in [0, 2PI]
this(in Vec2 center, float radius0, float radius1,
     float theta0, float theta1) 
{
    c = center;
    r0 = radius0;
    r1 = radius1;
    t0 = theta0;
    t1 = theta1;
}

@property Box2 box() {
    int k;

    if (t0 < PI/2)
        k = 0;
    else if (t0 < PI)
        k = 1;
    else if (t0 < 3*PI/2)
        k = 2;
    else    // must be in last quadrant
        k = 3;

    float dt = k * PI/2;
    Box2 b = box_with_t0_in_quad1(t0 - dt, t1 - dt);
    b.rotate90(k);      // rotate back an integer multiple of 90 degrees
    b.ctr = c;
    return b;
}

protected:
Box2 box_with_t0_in_quad1(float t0, float t1) 
in {
    assert(0 <= t0 && t0 < PI/2);
} body {
    double minX, minY, maxX, maxY;

    if (t1 < 2*PI - t0)
        maxX = r1 * cos(t0);
    else
        maxX = r1 * cos(t1);

    if (t1 <= PI/2) {
        maxY = r1 * sin(t1);
        minY = r0 * sin(t0);
        minX = r0 * cos(t1);
    }
    else {
        maxY = r1;
        if (t1 <= PI) {
            if (t1 - PI/2 > PI/2 - t0)
                minY = r0 * sin(PI - t1);
            else
                minY = r0 * sin(t0);
            minX = r1 * cos(PI - t1);
        }
        else {
            if (t1 <= 3*PI/4) 
                minY = r1 * sin(t1);
            else    // 2PI >= theta1 > 3*PI/4 
                minY = -r1;
            minX = -r1;
        }
    }

    // Return untranslated by center
    return Box2([minX, maxY], [maxX, minY]);        // coordinates on Y-axis are reversed in pixel rendering coords
}
}
```